# Display contents of an array in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, display

Im making a project where the list items are contents with multiple attributes (username and passoword). I want to make the listview only display the usernames and once the username is clicked it would show the users password in a toast message. Im new to programming so i would need a few hints.

I managed to make the class and add 2 users to the array list.
Any ideas on how i could make the listview only display the usernames and then the password once the username is clicked?

Thanks in advance :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        static class user {
            public String username;
            public String password;


        public user(String name, String pass) {
            username = name;
            password = pass;
            List<user> userList = new ArrayList<>();
            userList.add(new user("Tom", "Hello123"));
            userList.add(new user("Jack", "Hell1"));


        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it might look like just adding a if statement and depending on what you are useing as a check box, then you could edit accordingly.

```
if(username == "Tom" ){
     Toast.makeText(this, "Your password is: Hello123", LENGTH_LONG);
} else if (username == "Jack"){
     Toast.makeText(this, "Your password is: Hell1", LENGTH_LONG);
} else {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid or error found", LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you. Now i just need to find a way to get the username to be in the list view when i run the emulator

Comment: If you update your question with all the code, I might be able to help you out!